# Open-Close sections on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On [site](http://www.obbserv.com), scroll down few times to show tiles. Click any tile which will display two sections.

One from right, another from left side and overlays landing page.

Both sections can be exited by clicking close button on the right side.

How to do similar open-close effect of sections?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click','#boxes div', function(e){
  $('body').addClass('show-menus');
});

$(document).on('click','.close', function(e){
  $('body').removeClass('show-menus');
});
```

```css
#boxes div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:20%; padding-bottom:20%;
  background:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#boxes div:nth-child(even) {
  background:blue;
}
#boxes div:hover {
  opacity:0.5;
}

.left, .right {
  transition:600ms ease-in-out transform;
  position:fixed; top:0; height:100vh;
}

.left {
  background:green; width:60%;
  left:0;
  transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}

.right {
  background:purple; width:40%; 
  right:0;
  transform:translate3d(100%,0,0);
}

.show-menus .left, .show-menus .right {
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.right .close {
  position:absolute; 
  top:10px; right:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="boxes">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>

<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"><button class="close">close</button></div>
```

Comment: wow! .. and thanks for quick response.

I will soon integrate this into my page. :)